# I have a problem importing and using a small library (artifact) created on java and published on maven with sonatype

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, artifact

The url of library is:
Github: https://github.com/Roberto-Marcello/InjectModel
Maven: https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.github.roberto-marcello/inject-model/0.1.5/jar

I have published version 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.7 (Trying to fix the error)

I change the package name, change the artifact name and other things.

The problem is when i try to use the library inside a project, the message of error is Cannot resolve symbol 'InjectModel'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X79jT.png)

This image is trying import annotation from library

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcuqa.png)

And this is my file pom is my first library (artifact) on java and i don't find the error.

Solve problem of my small library for use it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEYM7.png)

I try to execute maven install or maven package and the error persist

Comment: Is this a pure editor-problem, i.e. does the project compile when you execute `mvn package`?

Comment: I believe that is just a typo: `inject-model` vs `inject_model`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). [Edit] your question to include the code/error messages as text instead.